# Evento de clique em um SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, onclick

Tenho um mapa do Brasil, num SVG, onde gostaria de apresentar uma `div` junto de cada estado  quando se clica no mesmo.

Consegui trabalhar a mudança de cor com `hover` usando o `ID` de cada estado do Brasil:

```
function highlight_map_states(){
  if($(".states_section").length>0){
     $(".states_section .list_states .item .link").hover(function(){
       var a="#state_"+$(this).text().toLowerCase();
       $(a).attr("class","state hover")
     },function(){
       var a="#state_"+$(this).text().toLowerCase();
       $(a).attr("class","state")
     })
  }
};
```

Como faço para ter um clique em cada estado a fazer aparecer uma `div`?

Nota: Não dá para colocar todo o código aqui porque a pergunta tem um tamanho máximo de caracteres, mas fica uma demo no [Codepen](http://codepen.io/fabiogoodoy/pen/wgipx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que estás à procura é o método [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) que te irá devolver um objeto [`ClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMClientRect) com a distância em pixeis para `top`, `right`, `bottom` e `left`.

> O método `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` retorna o tamanho de um elemento e a sua posição em relação à janela de exibição.

O valor devolvido é do tipo `float`, mas podes fazer uso do mesmo diretamente nas propriedades de CSS para o elemento a posicionar.

## Exemplo [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Exemplo do rato a passar por cima de uma `path`, onde aparece uma `<div/>` junto da mesma:

```
var $toolTip = $('.tooltip');

$('path').hover(function(){

    var t = this.getBoundingClientRect().top,   // distancia do topo
        l = this.getBoundingClientRect().left;  // distancia da esquerda

    $toolTip .css({
        "top": t + "px",
        "left": l + "px"
    }).show();
    
}, function(){
    $toolTip.hide();
});
```

Ver demonstração completa no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/k7a3q5xm/).

## Exemplo [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Exemplo de clique sobre uma `path` ou `circle` a fazer aparecer a `<div/>` junto do elemento clicado:

```
// Faz aparecer elemento junto da path ou circle que recebeu o clique
$('path, circle').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var t = this.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        l = this.getBoundingClientRect().left;

    $tooltip.css({
        "top": t + "px"
        "left": l + "px"
    }).show();
});

// Desabilita clique nas descrições e textos
$('desc, text').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Ver demonstração completa no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/v3s33w75/).

---

<sup>Não posso montar uma demonstrações aqui porque o máximo de caracteres na resposta é de 30000.</sup>

Comment: Entendi Zuul!! E como eu crio uma div diferente para cada estado?? Desculpa a ignorância rs pois eu não manjo nada de javascript! Muito obrigado ;)

Comment: @mdesigner Eu não sei para que queres as `div` nem o que vai estar dentro de cada uma para te aconselhar no melhor caminho. Mas não seria mais prático e simples ter as `div` no HTML, como a dos exemplos na resposta, e na altura de as utilizar, chamar o `.show()` para as apresentar ? Mas seja como for, ficam dois exemplos no JSFiddle para: Criar DIV com [JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/k1pnx0mw/) e criar DIV com [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/bcaeqoo8/).

Comment: Muito obrigado Zuul!!